# How can I define the number of rows on cfspreadsheet object?

Tags: coldfusion, rowcount, cfspreadsheet

I am in the process of learning ColdFusion and I am trying to work with spreadsheets using [spreadsheetFormatRows(spreadsheetObject, dataFormat, rangeOfRowsFormated)](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spreadsheetformatrows.html)

How can I set the range to include all of the rows, except the header row, which is for column name? Is there a function that returns the number of the rows on cfspreadsheet object, so I can set the range to '2-rowCount'?

I tried  `spreadsheetFormatRows(theSheet, headerFormat, 2-50);` and works fine and formats rows 2 to 50, but I don't want to have that hard-coded.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Keep track of the number of rows as you populate them and save the value to a variable.  Simpler yet, if they are query results, use the recordcount variable from cfquery.

Comment: Yes, it is a query and yes recordcount works perfect. Post it as an answer so I can marked it as the correct one for those one who comes to read the post later. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spreadsheet object has an attribute rowcount. You can do `spreadsheetFormatRows(theSheet, format, "2-#theSheet.rowCount#");`

```
<cfscript>
    mySheet = spreadSheetNew("My Sheet");
    spreadSheetAddRow(mySheet, "'Col. A','Col. B','Col. C'");
    for(i=1; i <= RandRange(1, 100); i++){
        spreadSheetAddRow(mySheet, "'Row A#i#','Row B#i#','Row C#i#'");
    }
    spreadSheetFormatRow(mySheet, {bold = true, fontsize = 24}, 1);
    spreadSheetFormatRows(mySheet, {fontsize = 16}, "2-#mySheet.rowcount#");
    cfheader(name = "Content-Disposition", value = 'inline; fileName="test.xls"');
    cfcontent(type="application/vnd.ms-excel", variable="#spreadSheetReadBinary(mySheet)#");
</cfscript>
```

[Try Online](http://trycf.com/gist/66b02ff1f8db717f814f1079fd391af7/acf2016?theme=monokai)

Comment: Would you not have to add 1 to format the last row?

Comment: @DanBracuk In the spreadsheet, header row/s are like any other row. If you have a data set of 25 items and 1 header row, you have 26 rows in your spreadsheet so 2-26. We do have a hard coded offset for the start of the formated range which is the same as 1+headers row count.

Comment: So editing your answer will in fact improve it then.

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of the number of rows as you populate them and save the value to a variable. Simpler yet, if they are query results, use the recordcount variable from cfquery.

Remember to add 1 so you format the last row.